# UEFI Debian installation onto USB via VMware (for use on another PC)

Tags: debian, usb, live-usb

I was thinking about installing the latest version of Debian onto a 32GB USB drive for use on my host PC. One of the reasons that I am doing this is so that I won't have to worry about a lengthy (and possibly corrupted) installation on my hard drive and I don't want to risk a dual boot either. I want to achieve this using VMware (as it has full UEFI support) and install AMDGPU 
afterwards. Is this possible? My host PC uses Linux Mint 17.3 and I don't want a corrupted GRUB.

My USB drive is a Sandisk Ultra if that affects anything.

If this is possible without VMware and works without having to buy an extra USB drive then that's also fine.

Comment: You can do this, does your hard drive not have space for the VM? Do you plan on doing GPU pass through?

Comment: I do have enough space for the VM and my setup doesn't support GPU passthrough (as I mentioned earlier, I will install the driver after the installation).

Comment: Well about the gpu, if you are not doing passthrough you will likely be using the virtual driver. There are some options with kvm/qemu but typically with virtual box and VMware they have their own drivers which should typically be installed by the guest os or respective guest additions. If you have space for the vm on the disk why do you want to use a flash drive?

Comment: That's not really what I mean. What I mean is that I'll only use the VM once to install the OS to the USB then that's it. After that, I should be able to configure the boot settings on my host PC to boot from it and install AMDGPU there. The plan is that I should be able to retain data upon reboots, as well as drivers. I hope it makes sense now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Using `qemu-img` to convert a `.vmdk`

Install `qemu-img`. It should be provided by the `qemu-kvm` package (`apt install qemu-kvm`)

Create the VM and then convert the image and write it to your USB using the following:

```
qemu-img -O raw NAME-OF-YOUR-VM.vmdk disk.img
dd if=/PATH/TO/disk.img of=/dev/sdX  # Where X is your flash drive
```

I will include a link to the `qemu-img` [manpage](https://linux.die.net/man/1/qemu-img) for additional information and options.

Now you should be able to boot off of your flash drive. Keep in mind that your USB flash drive needs to be large enough to fit the VM disk and that you will very likely need to change over from using virtual machine drivers to the correct ones for your hardware.

### Using Clonezilla

You can create your VM in VMware and then add a Clonezilla iso to be able to boot off of.  I will be following [this guide](https://www.howtoforge.com/converting-a-vmware-image-to-a-physical-machine) on how to do so.

1. Add the Clonezilla iso to your VMware CD drive to be able to boot off of it.
2. Add a new *physical* disk to your VMware by going to Add...(Under Hardware) -> Hard Drive -> Use a Physical Disk -> Select your Flash drive and then make sure that Use entire disk is selected and give it a name.
3. Boot your VM into Clonezilla, make sure to select the proper keymapping settings for your keyboard and locale.
4. Start Clonezilla and select the `device-device` option and continue.
5. Select Beginner mode, disk to local disk, and select the source disk (Your VMware disk) and the target disk (Your flash drive).

I leave it up to you to determine if you want to run a check and repair before and after cloning but once you are through you should have your VMware image converted to a bootable image on your flash drive. You will have to complete any repairs necessary just like with the `qemu-img` conversion.

Best of Luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help - this was what I was looking for the whole time! I'm going to try the QEMU method and see if that works.

Comment: Yep, it works. The only thing you need to change is that you will need to do "qemu-img convert -f vmdk -O raw NAME-OF-YOUR-VM.vmdk disk.img" instead of just "qemu-img NAME-OF-YOUR-VM.vmdk -O raw disk.img". Other than that, it works just fine.

Comment: @Richard fixed that. If this solution worked for you please accept it so others who stumble upon this post know that this is an acceptable answer for the question. Thank you.